# Enable to create PostGIS datastore using the geoserver-rest package

Tags: geoserver-rest-py

I want to create a PostGIS datastore and then publish my PostGIS table, the code I'm using is:

```
geo=Geoserver('http://127.0.0.1:9090/geoserver', username='admin', password='geoserver')
geo.create_featurestore(store_name="postgis",workspace="TEST",host="127.0.0.1",port=5433,db="DB",schema="public",pg_user="postgres",pg_password="password")

#geo.publish_featurestore(workspace='TEST', store_name='postgis', pg_table="regions")
```

there is nothing wrong with the code when I run it, and the paramateres are correct but when I go to GeoServer to see if the datastore was created I find that the datastore wasn't correctly created a "?" is written in the field "type" instead of 'POSTGIS'
and also those warnings in my CMD:

```
30 mars 17:10:15 WARN [geoserver.security] - Could not find factory for store : 
 DataStoreInfoImpl[postgis]. Unable to encrypt connection parameters.
30 mars 17:10:15 WARN [rest.catalog] - Unable to determine datastore type from connection parameters
30 mars 17:10:15 WARN [geoserver.security] - Could not find factory for store : DataStoreInfoImpl[postgis]. Unable to encrypt connection parameters.
30 mars 17:10:15 INFO [rest.catalog] - POST data store postgis
```

Comment: What documentation do you use as reference? The REST API documentation looks different https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/api/#1.0.0/datastores.yaml

Comment: I'm using geoserver-rest package https://pypi.org/project/geoserver-rest/

Comment: At least you seem to use double quotation marks in some places where the example in the documentation has single quotes. The project is interesting, it is active but none of the developers work with the core of GeoServer. Please edit your question and mention in the text that you use this Python package. It is talking with the GeoServer REST API but they are different things.